# Is it possible to override persistence.xml partially in Quarkus application properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

I'm migrating a JEE / JBOSS project to Quarkus.

In this project I've got a DAO which is shared by many EJB's (SOAP services, REST services). The DAO defines also the entities and the persistence.xml like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="broGmw">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/BroDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>x</class>
        <class>y</class>
        <!--> many more <-->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now, I know that the jta datasource is not yet supported in quarkus.

I don't want to redefine the same persistence.xml in each endpoint EJB in my JEE project. Also, removing it from the DAO library does not feel logical, since persistence.xml logically belongs to the DAO.

Quarkus however, does not tolerate the jta-data-source. So I want to redefine only the data-source in the application properties, leaving the persistence.xml in the DAO (library).

```
quarkus.datasource.broDs.db-kind=other
quarkus.datasource.broDs.username=xxx
quarkus.datasource.broDs.password=yyy
quarkus.datasource.broDs.jdbc.url=myUrl
quarkus.datasource.broDs.jdbc.driver=${QUARKUS-BRO-DATASOURCE-DRIVER:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver}

quarkus.hibernate-orm.broGmw.dialect=${QUARKUS-ORM-DIALECT:org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.oracle.OracleSpatial10gDialect}
quarkus.hibernate-orm.broGmw.log.sql=${QUARKUS-ORM-LOG-SQL:false}
#quarkus.hibernate-orm.broGmw.packages=... (here's where I want the content of my persistence.xml read)
quarkus.hibernate-orm.broGmw.datasource=broDs
```

However, Quarkus ignores this as soon when it finds the persistence.xml

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-14T22:28:38+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final:build (default) on project gmw_rest_dispatch: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Value found for #getJtaDataSource : not supported yet
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.LightPersistenceXmlDescriptor.verifyIgnoredFields(LightPersistenceXmlDescriptor.java:164)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.LightPersistenceXmlDescriptor.validateAndReadFrom(LightPersistenceXmlDescriptor.java:55)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.QuarkusPersistenceUnitDefinition.<init>(QuarkusPersistenceUnitDefinition.java:34)
```

How can I realize this?

Filtering the persistence.xml from the dependencies is perhaps also an option. I know that this is possible in the next version of Quarkus, but perhaps there's a generic mechanism to filter files (classes, xml) from the dependencies to make Quarkus ignore them.

Comment: working with plugin io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.0.CR1 I added:
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-DSKIP_PARSE_PERSISTENCE_XML=true</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
That does not work.. Stil looking how to do this.. ?

Comment: Hmm. I took a look at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/10107 and seems that you really have to run maven with a -D option.. Would be nice if you can specify it in the plugin somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SKIP_PARSE_PERSISTENCE_XML` property has to be passed when you run your Quarkus application, not when you build it.

Passing it to the `quarkus-maven-plugin` won't help.

It requires to be added to the maven build as `-D` property, configured in the IDE and in possible build scripts in CI/CD.

Comment: It actually fails during build

Comment: To show: I extended the error log a bit more